# Java exception handler for class

Tags: java, exception, aop

Is it possible to have a uniform exception handler for all instance methods of a class in Java? For example, if I have the class `Car`:

```
class Car {
  public void drive(double miles) {
     ...
  }

  public void turnLeft() {
    ...
  }
  
  public void turnRight() {
    ...
  }
}
```

Could I add a handler function that is called every time an exception is thrown by one of these methods? The ultimate goal would be to log all of these exceptions in a uniform way, even if they are ultimately caught and ignored by higher levels of the stack.

Comment: You mentioned AOP in the tags. Are you looking for a particular way of accomplishing this with a certain framework (AspectJ?)

Comment: @Zymus yes, a specific pattern to follow would be helpful. I have found the ExceptionHandler annotation for Spring, but I'm not sure if that works at the class-level.

Comment: With AspectJ you can easily do that. An around-advice with a pointcut targeting the classes and methods of your choice (all or just some) would be easy to implement. This works without any additional frameworks like Spring, Java EE, application servers, reactive stuff etc. It just works with normal POJOs. But of course, you can also use AspectJ from within those frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

Extend a Proxy to delegate Car. We can use jdk Proxy if car has a interface, or use cglib. Just like what some framework(Spring...) has provided.
Code below is a example of cglib.

```
class ErrorHandleProxy implements MethodInterceptor {
    public Object createProxy(Object target) {
        Enhancer enhancer = new Enhancer();
        enhancer.setSuperclass(target.getClass());
        enhancer.setCallback(this);
        enhancer.setClassLoader(target.getClass().getClassLoader());
        return enhancer.create();
    }

    @Override
    public Object intercept(Object obj, Method method, Object[] args, MethodProxy proxy) throws Throwable {
        Object ret = null;
        try {
            ret = proxy.invokeSuper(obj, args);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            /// do logging or rethrow exception
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

And then, we can call car with this Proxy

```
Car car = new Car();
Car proxy = (Car)new ErrorHandleProxy().createProxy(car);
proxy.xxx
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spring , then you can catch all exceptions in one class https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring Using an ExceptionMapper class.

If it is a normal app, in your public static void main you can surround your code in try catch to catch all exceptions.